# How to round datetime()?

Tags: python, time

What I want to do is perform time delta operations but rounding time to deciseconds (I am not sure if the term exists, but the following example should be self explanatory) instead of microseconds.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

tick = datetime.now()
time.sleep(1.5)
tock = datetime.now()
time.sleep(2.1)
tock2 = datetime.now()
diff1 = tock-tick
diff2 = tock2-tick
diff1 #0:00:01.500914
diff2 #0:00:03.601836
```

I would like the diff1 output to be `0:00:01.50`, respectively diff2 `0:00:03.60`. But I do not want to format the result, I want to format the time values I am recording with tick and tock, basically to round them (actually just cut out everything that follows the two digits after the dot). The reason is, at some point in my program I want to compare the two diffs (as rounded time deltas) and only then I want to turn the result into string and format it.

I have tried doing it like this

```
tick = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-4]
time.sleep(1.5)
tock = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-4]
diff1 = tock-tick
#TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

But does not work since it already converts the time to string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply take the [`total_seconds`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) from the timedelta and round that, constructing a new timedelta:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

tick = datetime.now()
time.sleep(1.5)
tock = datetime.now()
diff = tock-tick
diff = timedelta(seconds=round(diff.total_seconds(), 2))
print(diff)  # 0:00:01.500000
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for something like this. Thank you